# Go build fail, fatal error: rocksdb/c.h

Tags: go, build, blockchain, hyperledger

I am testing on project [obc-peer](https://github.com/openblockchain/obc-peer).

I am confused where should I get about github.com/**** , golang.org/**** , google.golang.org/**** , google/****.
Am I wrong about $GOPATH ?

Here is the log of go build and go env:

Hope someone can help me on it......Gods

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/opt/gopath$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/opt/gopath"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/openblockchain/obc-peer$ go build
# github.com/openblockchain/obc-peer/vendor/github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb
vendor/github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb/backup.go:4:24: fatal error: rocksdb/c.h: No such file or directory
 // #include "rocksdb/c.h"
                        ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: there is noting under /home/vagrant/go.what should $GOPATH be?

Comment: this is a very interesting problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed here and it is done.
https://github.com/openblockchain/obc-peer/issues/885

Configure RocksDB related deps

```
sudo apt-get install -y libsnappy-dev
sudo apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libbz2-dev
```

Run go install - CGO flags for RocksDB

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/openblockchain/obc-peer
CGO_CFLAGS="-I/opt/rocksdb/include" CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/opt/rocksdb -lrocksdb -lstdc++ -lm -lz -lbz2 -lsnappy" go install
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't installed rocksdb library

Comment: yes. you are correct. it is necessary to Configure RocksDB related deps and flags for RocksDB.

Comment: Yes. Or you can install gorocksdb with all the libraries embedded using 'go get -tags=embed github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb' 
Check here https://github.com/tecbot/gorocksdb#install

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rocksdb
```

before executing

```
CGO_CFLAGS="-I/opt/rocksdb/include" CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/opt/rocksdb -lrocksdb -lstdc++ -lm -lz -lbz2 -lsnappy" go install
```